# Retrieving Clob data from database using Servlet and make that data downloadable in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, download, clob

I have requirement where i need to retrieve some set of data, out of which one is CLOB data,may get multiple rows and i need to display each row in JSP page and also provide download option to download this CLOB data as an XML file for every row.

I have no idea how to implement this, below is code which i am using to retrieve the data.

```
List dataList = new ArrayList();

        while(rs.next()){
            RecordData rdata =new RecordData();
            rdata.setId(rs.getInt("OBJID"));    

            aclob = (CLOB)rs.getClob("X_MESSAGE");  
            clob_length = (int)aclob.length();  
            rdata.setMessage(aclob.getSubString(1, clob_length));

            dataList.add(rdata);
        }

request.setAttribute("dataList", dataList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/displayrecords.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"need to retrieve some set of data, out of which one is CLOB data,may get multiple rows and i need to display each row in JSP page and also provide download option to download this CLOB data as an XML file for every row."

In the code sample above you have solved the first half - to get the data, set in a bean and put that bean in to the session. Now in JSP iterate over it and show in a table.

For download - add an ID column to the table and to the bean, each download link will point to a download jsp along with the id as a param. In that jsp download the file. I would suggest clear the dataList from the session after rendering it as it will take up memory (RAM) on your JVM if there are many users or many rows

Comment: Thank you tgkprog, for your response.I have created a new variable in my bean `private int id;` I have a unique value in my table so i'm assigning this to the id...here's my modified  code,

Comment: Im not using any sessions. Updated above is my modified code can you please help with the jsp part.

Comment: you need to learn this your self suggest a java tutorial on jsps

Comment: since im passing whole clob data as string, i can use hyperlink as download which invokes servlet to there i can access this string value and make it downloadable as suggested here [http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/], but i want to understand your column id part as it sounds more logical :) appreciate your response

Comment: that would work too No data base hit so not so bad. Just that the data would travel from the browser to the server and then back to the user in a new mime type. both would work. Id just a unique id, get it particular row from db and send it to user.